# Display Hamburger Menu on iPad (or other tablet) in landscape mode

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, hamburger-menu

I'm working on a [WordPress website](http://yr-neu.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/). My issue is that on iPad landscape mode the navigation menu is displayed under the logo.

What I need is to display the "hamburger menu" on landscape too, as per the second image.

[image: Menu goes under the logo]

[image: Correct hamburger menu]

Answer (score 2):

From looking at your code you just need to change your media breakpoint from `@media only screen and (max-width: 979px)` to `@media only screen and (max-width: 1080px)` at around line 802 from what it looks like.